# Shopify call all articles in blog EXCEPT the first one

Tags: arrays, shopify, liquid

I am building a fancy blog page for my client. They want the first blog post shown full width with a bunch of other cool things showing, then they want the other posts displayed below in order they came out.

I have the fancy part worked out, but when I put the rest of the blog posts below that one, the first one still comes up.

Logically this makes sense because I am using `{% for article in blog.articles  %}` to call the posts, but is there any way I can skip just the first post when calling all the other posts for the blog?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shopify have an offset filter.

You can read more on it here: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/iteration-tags#offset

To sum it up your code will become `{% for article in blog.articles offset: 1  %}`

Comment: This works great! I still have a challenge now to face with this template, but thanks for your insight into the issue.